# Convergence of a series depending on a parameter

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n-1)^2+\alpha 2^n}$$
I have to find for which $\alpha$ this series converges.
I tried the ratio test but I get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right|=1$ and it tells me nothing of convergence of this series. 
I also tried Raabe's test and I get that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \cdot (\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)= \infty$.

I don't know how to continue.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The situation is mildly different for $\alpha\gt 0$ than for $\alpha\lt 0$. Take $\alpha\gt 0$. Your ratio test calculation was not right.

Comment: The ratio test proof of convergence for $\alpha\gt 0$ will be  easier if before applying it you note that the $n$-th term is positive and $\lt \frac{n}{\alpha 2^n}$.

Comment: Thank you, I can solve it now.

Comment: You are welcome. For $\alpha\lt 0$ it is the same but we need to use absolute value.  Again convergence.  And for $\alpha=0$, divergence by  comparison with harmonic series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $3$ cases:

$1)$ $\alpha =0$ the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n-1)^2}$$ diverges by comparison test with harmonic series. Indeed the series :$$\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac {1}{n}$$ diverges.

$2)$ $\alpha> 0$ the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n-1)^2+\alpha 2^n}$$ converges. Indeed $$ \frac{n}{(n-1)^2+\alpha 2^n}\sim_{+\infty} \frac{n}{\alpha 2^n}$$ that converges by root test. Indeed $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left (\frac{n}{\alpha 2^n}\right )^{\frac {1}{n}}= \frac {1}{2}<1$$

$3)$ $\alpha<0$ the series converges absolutely. In this case you have need of absolute value.